# Error in R package 'unmarked', when applying function occuMulti()

Tags: r, habitat-modeling, wildlife-ecology

I'm trying t write an multi-species occupancy model with two species (M. martes and M. foina). However, I get a strange error message every time I try.

Here is the model how I want it to work:

```
fit_2 <- occuMulti(detformulas = c('~ tree_cover', '~tree_cover'),
                   stateformulas = c('~ distance2settlement',
                                     '~ distance2settlement',
                                     '~ distance2road',
                                     '~ distance2road',
                                     '~ tree_cover',
                                     '~ tree_cover',
                                     '~ ndvi',
                                     '~ ndvi'),
                   maxOrder = 2,
                   data = msom_data)
```

If I try this model, I get this error message:

`Error in .local(umf, ...) : 3 formulas are required in stateformulas list`

The model works, if I reduce the elements in the stateformulas vector on 3, like this:

```
fit_3 <- occuMulti(detformulas = c('~ tree_cover', '~tree_cover'),
                   stateformulas = c('~ distance2settlement',
                                     '~ distance2settlement',
                                     '~ distance2road'),
                   maxOrder = 2,
                   data = msom_data)
```

This doesn't make much sense for the analysis.

My data is in an unmarked frame for multi-species occupancy analyses `unmarkedFrameOccuMulti()`. This frame is (as far as I understand it) basically a list of thsese 3 parts:

- Part 1 (=y): a list of the detection history of Species_1 and Secies_2
- Part 2 (=siteCovs): site covariates as a data.frame
- Part 3 (=obsCovs): observation covariates, which are missing in my case, because I don't have any. Here is the code of how I definded my data set:

```
y_list <- list(martes = detection_history_martes,
               foina = detection_history_foina)

msom_data <- unmarkedFrameOccuMulti(y = y_list,
                                    siteCovs = cov_scaled,
                                    obsCovs = NULL)
```

Here is the summary() Output of my data:

```
> summary(msom_data)
unmarkedFrame Object

1270 sites
2 species: martes foina 
Maximum number of observations per site: 53
Mean number of observations per site:
martes: 5.15354330708661  foina: 5.15354330708661
Sites with at least one detection:
martes: 134  foina: 57
Tabulation of y observations:
martes:
    0     1  <NA>
 6356   189 60765
foina:
    0     1  <NA>
 6460    85 60765

Site-level covariates:
hm_2016            distance2road      distance2road_v2
Min.   :-1.61783   Min.   :-1.14448   Min.   :-1.07161
1st Qu.:-0.84395   1st Qu.:-0.71307   1st Qu.:-0.69790
Median :-0.14686   Median :-0.28754   Median :-0.30754
Mean   :-0.02776   Mean   : 0.01753   Mean   : 0.01436
3rd Qu.: 0.68764   3rd Qu.: 0.48677   3rd Qu.: 0.43367
Max.   : 2.75336   Max.   : 4.08021   Max.   : 4.80733

distance2settlement
Min.   :-0.43303
1st Qu.:-0.43303
Median :-0.43303
Mean   :-0.03354
3rd Qu.:-0.32731
Max.   : 8.26745

ndvi               tree_cover         elevation       
Min.   :-4.68916   Min.   :-2.251723   Min.   :-0.96288
1st Qu.:-0.46929   1st Qu.:-0.616720   1st Qu.:-0.79435
Median : 0.20780   Median : 0.255281   Median :-0.34575
Mean   :-0.01016   Mean   :-0.001399   Mean   : 0.02032
3rd Qu.: 0.67801   3rd Qu.: 0.800282   3rd Qu.: 0.60962
Max.   : 1.83190   Max.   : 1.381616   Max.   : 3.35137

deployment_id
EuCam_2021_100:   1
EuCam_2021_101:   1
EuCam_2021_102:   1
EuCam_2021_103:   1
EuCam_2021_104:   1
EuCam_2021_105:   1
(Other)       :1264
```

I work with data from camera traps, from multiple projects. Because of those many projects, I have many NAs in the detectionHistory table, since each of the camera deployments was just operating for  a few weeks to three months. The covariates are scaled.

I use the latest version of R and the lates version of the package 'unmarked'.

Comment: The number of formulae in that parameter is related to the data. It should be the same as the number of columns in the `fDesign` component of the data. Can you show a summary of your data? How have you constructed this? The example in `?occuMulti` is quite fiddly-looking...

Comment: Shure, I added it to the problem description above - Is that what you meant?. What is A ```fDesign``` by the way? sry I'm pretty new to this and till yet never heard of it.  I'd be happy if you could help me out with that :)

Comment: and yes, the example in the R package description didn't help me neither :D